# Bubble sorting a linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have created a linked list of 5 nodes of type:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int i;
    struct node* link;
}node;

node* head = NULL;
```

When printing out, this gives:

```
4 3 2 1 0
```

The head pointer is set to point at 4. I have then written a function to bubble sort the linked list as follows:

```
void sort(void)
{
     node* cur = head;
     node* next = cur->link;
     node* prev = NULL;

     while(cur->i > next->i)
     {
        printf("cur is greater than next\n");

        while(prev != head)
        {
          cur->link = next->link;
          next->link = cur;
          head = next;
          next = cur->link;
          prev = head;
        }
        while(next != NULL)
        {
          prev->link = next; 
          cur->link = next->link;
          next->link = cur;
          prev = next;
          next = cur->link;
        }
        printf("second while loop exited\n");

        for (node* ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->link)
        {
           printf("%d", ptr->i);
        }

        cur = head;
        next = cur->link;

      } 
}
```

There are various printf statements to check that the program is working. What I find is that after the first run-through, 4 is successfully bubbled up as follows:

```
3 2 1 0 4
```

However, after re-setting the cur pointer to 3 and next to 2, the next run-through provides the following:

```
2 1 0 4 3
```

Ultimately, we finish with

```
0 4 3 2 1
```

So as can be seen "3", "2" and "1" are being bubbled up too far. I have tried various conditonals in place of the third while loop to correct this but in the majority of cases this leads to seg faults. Of course, the other thing here is that my logic could be completely wrong and there may be a better way to implement this. Could you get away with just swapping the contents of nodes and not pointers themselves? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: write out on a paper exactly what you want each step to do, then step through it in a debugger, and compare.

Comment: How does your code work for the list `0 4 3`? The outer loop seems to skip any processing on the first comparision due to zero being not greater than four, thus `(cur->i > next->i)` being false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinary bubble-sort implementations for sorting arrays make use of the direct addressing and a known size of the array: they naturally use indices, that is ordinal numbers of items, so they can easily shrink the area sorted as the work progresses, because they know how many items are already on their final places.

A linked list is processed purely sequentially, so it doesn't allow such simple optimization without adding artificial 'index', incremented along the list iteration. That's why it's easiest to iterate always through the whole list and terminate when no more items were swapped, hence the list is sorted:

```
void sort(void)
{
    int swapped = 1;

    while(swapped)
    {
        node **prev = &head, *curr, *next;

        swapped = 0;
        for(curr = head; curr; prev = & curr->link, curr = curr->link)
        {
            next = curr->link;

            if(next && curr->i > next->i)
            {
                curr->link = next->link;
                next->link = curr;
                *prev = next;

                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT – some explanations** in reply to questions in Matthew2015 comments.

Logical conditions in C expect a numeric or pointer expression which are considered 'true' if they are different from zero or different from NULL, respectively. That means `while(swapped)` is essentially equivalent to `while(swapped != 0)` and `next && ...` is equivalent to `next != NULL && ...`. The condition in `while(swapped != 0)` means the loop will terminate when some execution of internal `for` does not set `swapped` to `1`, which happens when no item in the list is greater than its successor – that is, when the list is sorted.

The `for` loop condition expression is `curr` alone, equivalent to `curr != NULL`. That makes the `for` loop iterate along the list until there is no 'current' node.

The `node **prev` variable points to a pointer, which points to the current node. When the 'current' and the 'next' node need to be swapped, then the 'previous' link should no longer point to the 'current' node but to the 'next' node instead. Of course one might keep the pointer to the 'previous node' and assign a new value to the `(previous node)->link` — but that would not work in case of the first node in a list, which has no 'previous node' but is pointed to by the `head` variable. One must use additional condition to verify if the current node is the first node to resolve this inconsistency. Having a pointer to pointer, which originally points to `head` and then to `'previous node'.link` makes the whole code much simpler, shorter and also a bit faster.

Comment: Hi @CiaPan. This is a really elegant solution and it works beautifully. However, there are aspects of the code which I fail to fully understand. For example, you say "while(swapped)". Does this mean while swapped is equal to 0 or 1 or neither? What terminates this while loop? In the for loop,  prev and curr are constantly updated until what point? Normally you would say until curr != NULL, but you have just written "curr" What does this signify?

Comment: Additional questions would be: What is the purpose of "next" in if(next &&...)? What is the purpose of *prev = next? Why declare a pointer to a pointer in the first place? How are you ensuring that the head pointer is always at the start of the list?

Comment: The answer is too long for the comment space so I appended it to the answer above.

Comment: @Matthew2015 Adding an explicit ping as I'm unsure if you received a notification on the previous comment.

Comment: Hi @CiaPan. Thanks for the above explanation. That is very clear! I was going to say, I managed to adapt your code to be used for sorting linked lists within a hash table. This works fine for if(next && cur->val > next->val). However, I then modified the code for sorting strings, reading: if(next && cmp > 0), where cmp refers to: int cmp = strcmp(cur->word, next->word). It didn't seem to like this though. Any ideas why that could be? Cheers again

Comment: @Matthew2015 Do you check for `next != NULL` prior to calling `strcmp` on `next->word`...? PS. It is quite a separate problem — consider asking a new question. You may also link a new question to this one if you think this one makes an important background, but it's better to make a new question complete and self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the third `while`

```
    while(next != NULL)
    {
      prev->link = next; 
      cur->link = next->link;
      next->link = cur;
      prev = next;
      next = cur->link;
    }
```

Here you're always moving elements without testing whether they have to be moved - i.e. `cur->i > next->i`.

By the way, if it's guard is true, the second `while` gets executed only once and so it's the same as an `if` so I would use an `if`, at least for clarity reasons.